# Change how Outlook appointment is displayed in calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Is there a way to change how an appointment is displayed?  I'm thinking about writing an Outlook Addin that allows you to relate appointments/meetings to an external system and show some indication of the relationship in the calendar.  Basically, I want to add some text and an icon to specific appointments/meetings.

Is this possible?  How?

Answer (score -1):

Should be. You can modify the form or create a FormRegion and attach it to the appointment (then tie it together with a check against your data).

Unfortunately I'm still making my way through Outlook myself, but given what I know it should be possible. I went and just got [Add-In Express](http://www.add-in-express.com) just for the sake of cutting down development time and using their form manager to just select which items I want to associate the form region to.

Comment: There's more to it than a "little bit of code". You create an add-in in VS, make a form region that shows the information you need (bound to the Item you're interested in), tie that together with whatever method you're using to look-up the flag(s), then display the result. You also, in your 1st revision, only asked IF it was possible (so I provided the a method you could use).

Comment: I realize there is overhead associated with writing an Office addin.  I also know there are multiple approaches to hooking into Outlook and need to know which one would work best for this situation.  Thanks!

Comment: [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/MyContacts.aspx) may be of some help then. In one of the screen shots you can see how it allows you to attach it to the `Outlook.AppointmentItem` From there, program it like a normal win-forms with the datasource linking.

Comment: Thats definitly closer to what I'm looking for but I'm needing to alter an appointment on the calendar.  Thanks